# How in xcode to position the elements with pixel having a screenshot?

Tags: ios, xcode, layout, interface, screenshot

I have a screenshot of iPhone interface (buttons,textfield).I must to position this  elements in storyboard equivalent to screenshot with pixel. How can I do? Which program I can to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the tool **"Free Ruler"** for measuring on screen in pixels, inches, picas or cm.
Here's a [download link](http://www.pascal.com/software/freeruler/) for the same.
Hope this Helps! :)